# Get correct coordinates when mirroring layout

Tags: windows, right-to-left

I have a multilingual dialog, so the window layout MIGHT be RTL or LTR.

Problem is, the coordinates I get in WM_LBUTTONDOWN message (et al), are mirrored when RTL is set.

I need the coordinates unified for both layouts as LTR.

I've tried using GetCursorPos and then ScreenToClient, but it also gets mirrored.

Any idea?

Comment: [MapWindowPoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapwindowpoints).

Comment: Tried MapWindowPoints, same results as ScreenToClient.